# Javascript/jQuery function yields undefined in <IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

A short while back I asked a question here about how I could calculate when a heading was longer than one line within a given container, and subsequently wrap each of these lines in a `<span>`:

[Use Javascript/jQuery to determine where a heading breaks to the next line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960336/use-javascript-jquery-to-determine-where-a-heading-breaks-to-the-next-line)

I chose an answer which worked great for me, at least until I checked in IE7 and IE6, in which all the headings handled by this script rendered as

"**undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined**[...]"

on the page. As I'm not really a JavaScript person (that's why I asked such a question in the first place), it's really tough for me to figure out where the problem is. I assumed an undefined variable or something, but I just can't seem to grasp it.

Can anyone help?

I'll repeat the code here, but please refer to the link above for context:

```
$(function(){
  $h = $('.fixed').find('h3');
  $h.each(function(i,e){
    var txt = $(e).text();
    $th = $('<h3 />').prependTo($(e).parent());
    var lh = $(e).text('X').height();
    $(e).text('');
    while (txt.length > 0) {
        $th.text($th.text() + txt[0]);
        txt = txt.slice(1);
        if (($th.height() > lh) || (txt.length <= 0)) {
            var shc = $th.text().split(' ');
            var ph = shc.slice(0,-1).join(' ')+' ';
            if (txt.length <= 0) { ph += shc.pop(); }
            $('<span />').text(ph).appendTo($(e));
            $th.text(shc.pop());
        }
    }
    $th.remove();
  })
});
```

Comment: out of curiousity, does it work in other browsers (firefox, chrome, etc)

Comment: `I chose an answer which worked great for me, at least until I checked in IE7 and IE6` - read the question first lol

Comment: @galambalazs the question states is it works in IE8 and not 6 or 7.  It says nothing of other browsers.

Comment: @Matt it works fine in FF, Opera, Safari and Chrome (but using Dragonfly or Firebug, I do get "undefined", but these browsers are apparently more forgiving and render the actual headings anyway).

Comment: @Matt this was posted by the person who answered my previous question: http://jsfiddle.net/NkJzT/8/

Comment: @stephenhay I'd test it, but don't have IE7 or 6 anywhere handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
$th.text($th.text() + txt[0]);
```

to be

```
$th.text($th.text() + txt.charAt(0));
```

IE<8 doesn't accept string positions through array indexes ;)

The styling doesn't work, but that'll be a CSS issue which I couldn't fix before leaving. But everything is wrapped in spans :)

Comment: THAT WAS IT! The CSS wasn't a problem-- I've got it all working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing jumps out at me.  But, since you mentioned in your comment to your question that you see "undefined" in Firebug, I would start there.  Even though those browsers are failing gracefully, the fact that you see undefined there is your first hint to finding the problem for the harder-to-diagnose IE6/7.  I would use Firebug and either breakpoint in the function, or use some console.log() calls to document what the values that you are working with are each step of the way.  Once you start seeing undefined... you have likely found your problem.